# improper integral converge or diverge

Tags: integration

I need to determine whether the improper integral converges or not:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}\right)dx$

any ideas how to start?

Edit: What I've done:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{e^{x}-e^{-x}} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2x} - \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{x}-e^{-x}} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x} - \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{x}-e^{-x}} = $$

It seems to me that the left one diverges but the integral actually converges

Thanks!

Comment: try $k=\exp(x)$

Comment: I'll try thanks!

Comment: Far from the origin the integrand function behaves like $\frac{1}{2x}$, hence the given integral is blatantly divergent, you do not need any substitution.

Comment: @MarkViola I think you want $\ge C/x$ in place of $O(1/x).$

Comment: @zhw. Yes, I certainly abused the notation to mean $\sim$.

Comment: Oh pooey, I don't like it when the problem changes.

Comment: Ye should I open an other post for that?

Comment: I would suppose so, since multiple answers have already been received and much discussion has already ensued.

Comment: Okay doing it right now

Comment: fixed to the original one and asked in another post

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x>1$:

$$\frac1{2x}-\frac1{e^x-e^{-x}}>\frac1{2x}-\frac1{e^x-\frac12e^x}=\frac1{2x}-2e^{-x}$$

But the integral

$$\int_1^\infty\frac1{2x}-2e^{-x}~\mathrm dx$$

diverges to $+\infty$, hence by the comparison test for divergence, the given integral diverges as well.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the integrand has singularities at $x=0$ and $x\to \infty$.  The singularity at $x=0$ is removable since we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{2x}-\frac{1}{e^x-e^{-x}}&=\frac1{2x}-\frac{1}{2x+O(x^3)}\\\\
&=O(x)\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to 0
\end{align}$$

However, we note that as $x\to \infty$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{2x}-\frac{1}{e^x-e^{-x}}=\frac1{2x}+o\left(\frac1{x}\right)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the integral of interest diverges logarithmically.

Comment: No need to introduce big-o notation

Comment: Why not?  Variety is good.

Comment: I still don't understand why the split I did is wrong? Linearity is maintained in improper integrals $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)+g(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)+\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)$

Comment: @user21312 That only holds assuming those integrals exist.

Comment: @user21312 Good question.  If both integrals converge, then the sum of the integrals is equal to the integral of the sum.  Here, we don't know a priori that both integrals converge.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You beat me by 7 seconds.

Comment: Huehue, am a quick one aren't I?

Comment: Well, quick is good in some things, but not all things ... ;-))

Comment: @MarkViola You're having a fun day with big $O$ and little $o$ notation. You don't want $o(1),$ you want $o(1/x).$

Comment: @MarkViola Note that $-1/(2x) =o(1).$